# ElasticSearch exact match on text in nested field - Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The mapping contains nested field.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do an exact match on "value" without changing its type to *"keyword"*.

```
"mappings": {
"properties": {
  "tag": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "value": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "key": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Below is the code I tried to do an exact match on "value" field.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQ = boolQuery();
boolQ.must(matchQuery("tag.key", "key"));
boolQ.must(matchQuery("tag.value", "value").fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO));
entireQuery.must(nestedQuery("tag", boolQ, ScoreMode.None));
```

The above returned a result matched with tokenized words of "value" as well.

I would really appreciate if any references related to the question is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tag.value` is of type `text`, its content has been analyzed and the resulting tokens (i.e. not exact value) have been indexed in Elasticsearch.

Even though the `term` query doesn't analyze the search token, it doesn't help here because the indexed tokens have already been analyzed.

There are now two options:

A. If `tag.value` only contains a single token (e.g. `"Dog"`), you can still match them exactly by using either `term` or `match` but **by lowercasing** the value, as in:

```
{
    "nested": {
       "path": "tag",
       "query":{
           "term":{
               "tag.value":"dog"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

B. If `tag.value` contains multiple tokens (e.g. `"the big dog"`), it is therefore not possible to search for their exact value anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking for "term query" which returns the "documents that contain an exact term in a provided field".

```
    {
        "query":{
            "term":{
                "value":"your input"
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the reference of the same:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: In the documentation, it is stated to `avoid using the term query for text fields`, which makes sense since the value of the text field has been analyzed at indexing time. The `term` query will simply not analyze the term given as input to the search but cannot change the way the field value was analyzed and indexed into Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Term query`, which returns the documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

For more reference visit the below,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: In the documentation, it is stated to `avoid using the term query for text fields`, which makes sense since the value of the text field has been analyzed at indexing time. The `term` query will simply not analyze the term given as input to the search but cannot change the way the field value was analyzed and indexed into Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Use match phrase

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "message": "7000-8900"
        }
    }
}
```

In java use matchPhraseQuery of QueryBuilder

```
QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("message", "7000-8900");
```